# Abrir galeria, selecionar e salvar endereço no banco de dados - Android

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sqlite, galeria

Queria saber como posso abrir a galeria no meu aplicativo android em tempo de execução, selecionar uma imagem e copiar essa imagem para uma pasta do meu aplicativo no SD card e salvar o caminho da imagem no banco de dados, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Para abrir sua galeria você utiliza esse codigo no seu botão ou algo do tipo que vai clicar para poder abrir a galeria

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
            getString(R.string.get_gallery_picture)),
            Constants.RequestCodes.GET_GALLERY_PICTURE);
```

no onActivityResult implemente isso

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case Constants.RequestCodes.GET_GALLERY_PICTURE:
        getPictureFromGallery(resultCode, data);
        break;
    }
}
```

depois utilize esse metodo

```
private void getPictureFromGallery(int resultStatus, Intent data) {
    if (resultStatus == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        try {
            File image = File.createTempFile(getFilename(), ".jpg",
                    ImageHelper.getStorageDir(this));
            picturePath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
            ImageDecoderWorker imageDecoder = new ImageDecoderWorker(this,
                    this, image.getName());
            imageDecoder.execute(data.getData());
            loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TipUApplication.APP_TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            showAlert(R.string.default_title_error,
                    R.string.get_gallery_picture_error_message);
        }
    }
}
```

lembrando que isso são trechos do meu código você tem que alterar para sua maeira